# Do we say 星期五早上 or 早上星期五?

Tags: translation

Would we literally say Friday morning (星期五早上) in Chinese or the morning of Friday (早上星期五)? Do we say the day first or the time of the day? 
Thanks,
Soccergirl

Comment: I will vote up "星期五早上"， we also add like "凌晨" "早上" "中午" "下午" "傍晚" "晚上" "半夜" from day to midnight. To describe it.

Answer (score 2):

In China, we usually use "xīngqí wǔ zǎoshang".
今天早上
明天早上
下星期一下午
We always put the time of a day after the day.

Answer (score 1):

Friday morning is right

But xīngqí wǔ zǎoshang should be xīng qī wǔ zǎo shàng

Comment: Notes about the tones in your reply: The original tone for 星期 (xīngqí) "week", is the official standard in Taiwan. Also, 早上 should have a neutral tone in both standards.

Answer (score 1):

When referring to time, always say it before the verb. The order is:

Year/month/week -->

What day (今天/明天/昨天 or 星期幾）->

Time of day (早上/下午/晚上）->

Hour (幾點)

Verb.

So the correct order would be, yes, 星期五早上.

Answer (score 0):

The time in Chinese always goes from the biggest to the smallest. That is:

year > month > day > day of the week > period of the day > hour > minute > second

So, in your case, 星期五 xingqiwu (the day of the week) is bigger than 早上 zaoshang (the period of the day) and you should say:

> 星期五早上 xingqiwu zaoshang.